# Add UIView to cover the whole UITableViewCell along with accessory view in iOS 10

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a fairly easy custom cell with standard accessory view.

At some point I need to perform an animation of covering a whole cell with a colored view which has an image in its center. I am experiencing strange issues on iPhone 5 with iOS 10.2 while I am doing that.

This is what I do:

1. Create subclass of UITableViewCell with nib file.
2. Add a UIView `coverView` as a subview directly (`self.addSubview(self.coverView)`) to my custom cell (since I need to cover accessory view too, I can't add it to `contentView`) in init methods. The `coverView` is created programmatically with no layout constraints. The UIImageView is added into it programmatically with layout constraints and `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false`.
3. Add a method:

   func animateCState() {

   ```
   self.coverView.frame = self.bounds
   self.coverView.frame.origin.y = -self.frame.size.height
   self.bringSubview(toFront: self.coverView)
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.coverView.frame.origin.y = 0
   })
   ```

   }
4. Call `animateCState` when user taps on the cell

What I expect: *green view with image in center slides from top*

What I get: *Apparently transparent view slides from top, and blinks to green almost at the end of animation. I can see imageView sliding in proper position.*

Question: how to add a view which will cover the whole UITableViewCell (with accessory view) to a cell and be able to animate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It seems I have figured it out.

Apparently UITableView or UITableViewCell does something (set `.clear` color as background) to all views added directly to a cell either after `prepareForReuse` or at some other point in time. I had to set the color I want in my `animateCState` function right before I do animation.

So my method that works looks like this:

```
func animateCState() {

    self.coverView.frame = self.bounds
    self.coverView.frame.origin.y = -self.frame.size.height
    self.bringSubview(toFront: self.coverView)
    self.coverView.backgroundCOlor = .green
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.coverView.frame.origin.y = 0
    })  
}
```